# Load correctly jQuery UI tabs through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have some tabs on a web page in my website using jQuery UI and I want to load them dynamically in another web page on the same domain. I've used the AJAX `load()` function, by clicking on some elements, but when I click on them I get what I am not really expecting to get, or so I get only the html structure without any visual jQuery tab, although I've loaded correctly all the needed and indispensable links in the head; maybe I can explain it better with this example:
( in this example all I want to do is to load some div elements from a page A into a page B, obviously all this will take place just in the page B )

page A

```
    <div id="tabs" ui-tabs>
        <ul ui-tabs-nav>
            <li><a href="#fragment-1">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-2">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-3">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="fragment-1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
        <div id="fragment-2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
        <div id="fragment-3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit  
        </div>
    </div>
```

Page B

```
<body>
    <div id="box">

    </div>
    <span id="button" style="cursor:pointer;">button</span>       
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#button").click(function(){
                $("#box").load("paginaA.html #tabs"); 
            });
        });              
    </script>
</body>
```

So, the tabs with id="tabs" should appear just right in the div with the id="box". Does someone explain me why this shouldn't happen to me?
I apologize for my bad-English!

I have these two pages and I want simply to let appear dynamically some divs from a page into another by clicking on some links; now I've just created a jsFiddle page which is linking to another jsFiddle page like as my aim, so it has the same purpose. You will see that the jQuery UI tabs won't appear properly and that's my actual problem. Here the links are: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mktgnp3e/59/) this is where the div is and it has id="boxDrag", and [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mktgnp3e/58/) is where there's the div with id="boxTab" in which I would like to make the "boxDrag" appear into, by clicking on the "click here" button. So these two pages simulate the two pages on my website.

Comment: You need to add the classes here  <div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs">
        <ul class="ui-tabs-nav"> that's step 1

Comment: It doesn't work ...

Comment: Ah right I see what you want to do. Right the classes are needed but this .load part you need to do an ajax call - load in the html into the relevent part and call the function jquery ui to enable the tabs

Comment: doesn't work this time neither ...

Comment: I edited the question adding something ... hope it can be helpful

Comment: right ok, I see the issue. You need to call something to make the tabs load.
e.g ( "#box" ).load( "paginaA.html #tabs", function() {
  $(".tabs").tabs({});
});
Should do

Comment: Read the docs. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: ( "#box" ).load( "paginaA.html #tabs", function() { $(".tabs").tabs({}); }); works like a charm to me!! This is what I needed specifically: " { $(".tabs").tabs({}); });" as a parameter of the load() function. Thank you sooo much pal !!! I really appreciate this !! Thank you again ;)

Comment: No worries - glad to help - just tick the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
( "#box" ).load( "paginaA.html #tabs", function() { $(".tabs").tabs({}); })
```